# LeetCode : Three Sums(Cannot implicitly convert type)

Tags: c#

> Given array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

Note:

The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

Example:

```
Given array nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4],

A solution set is:
[
  [-1, 0, 1],
  [-1, -1, 2]
]
```

```cs
     public class Solution {
            public IList<IList<int[]>> ThreeSum(int[] nums) {
                IList<IList<int[]>> solutionList = new List<IList<int[]>>();
                List<int[]> sublist= new List<int[]>();
                int checkNum,solCounter=0;
                List<int> tempList;
                for(int z =  0; z<nums.Length;z++){
                 for(int t = nums.Length;z<t;t--)
                 {
                     if(nums[t]!=nums[z])
                     { 
                         checkNum=nums[z]+nums[t];
                        tempList=nums.ToList();
                         tempList.RemoveAt(t);
                        tempList.RemoveAt(z);
                        for(int y = 0; y<tempList.Count;y++){
                             if(checkNum-tempList[y]==0)
                             {
                                 
                                sublist.Add(new int[] {z,t,y});
                                 solutionList.Add(sublist[solCounter]);
                                 solCounter++;
                             }
                             }
                      }
                     else{
                         continue;
                     }
                    
                    }
                } 
                return solutionList;
            }
    
    }
```

getting these errors;

> Line 19: Char 16: error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Collections.Generic.IList<int[]>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Collections.Generic.IList>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (in **Driver**.cs)

And:

> Line 21: Char 43: error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<int[]>' (in Solution.cs)

Comment: I believe you can fix the first compiler error by adding `using System.Linq`

Comment: can you point out line 19 and line 21 in the code?

Comment: The error is on `solutionList.Add(sublist[solCounter]);` and it is indeed trying to add the wrong type of object. I realise that part of programming is knowing when to ask for help, but isn't the point of solving puzzles like these to try do it yourself? These are **compiler errors** which means the compiler is literally telling you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @stuartd you are absolutely right about solving puzzles, and I wasn't really asking about my algorithm, just wanted to understand why did I get this compiler error thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about your bug, doesn't seem to be heading to an optimal solution though. This solution is `O(N ^ 2)`, which will get accepted. I don't think `O(N ^ 3)` algorithms would get accepted for this problem, I might be wrong:

```
public class Solution {
    public IList<IList<int>> ThreeSum(int[] nums) {
        IList<IList<int>> res = new List<IList<int>>();

        if (nums.Length < 3) {
            return res;
        }

        
        int start = 0;
        int lo;
        int hi;
        int target;
        Array.Sort(nums);
        while (start < nums.Length - 2) {
            target = -nums[start];
            lo = -~start;
            hi = nums.Length - 1;

            while (lo < hi) {
                if (nums[lo] + nums[hi] > target) {
                    hi--;

                } else if (nums[lo] + nums[hi] < target) {
                    lo++;

                } else {
                    List<int> Init = new List<int>() { nums[start], nums[lo], nums[hi] };
                    res.Add(Init);

                    while (lo < hi && nums[lo] == Init[1]) {
                        lo++;
                    }

                    while (lo < hi && nums[hi] == Init[2]) {
                        hi--;
                    }
                }

            }

            int currStart = nums[start];

            while (start < nums.Length - 2 && nums[start] == currStart) {
                start++;
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

#### If you are preparing for [interviews](https://leetcode.com/problemset/top-interview-questions/?listId=wpwgkgt):

- We would want to write [bug-free](https://www.codegrip.tech/productivity/tips-to-write-bug-free-code-during-interview/) and [clean](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-cleaner-code-during-onsite-interviews) codes based on standards and conventions (e.g., [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>[1](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html), [2](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eeno/coding/CCodingStandard.html)</sup>, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), [2](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)</sup>, [java](/questions/tagged/java)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), [2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)</sup>, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)</sup>, [python](/questions/tagged/python)<sup>[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)</sup>, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)</sup>, [go](/questions/tagged/go)<sup>[1](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments)</sup>, [rust](/questions/tagged/rust)<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/)</sup>).